# Is there an example for exporting im2txt checkpoint model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am finding it hard to export a trained im2txt model checkpoint. Are there any examples documentation on how to export an already trained `show and tell` or any other image captioning model ?

Comment: What is the specific issue? If you look at [run_inference.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py) in the im2txt repo you'll see how to load the model and make predictions from it.